# Xamarin Designer Won't Load

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been working on trying to get Xamarin functioning for a while with Visual Studio 2015, with no luck. The designer won't load and throws one of two exceptions:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\mc_asturley\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesigner8664439545839624740.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at mono.android.JniHelper.loadEmbeddedJniLibrary(JniHelper.java:28)
    at mono.android.D3DImageFactory.<clinit>(D3DImageFactory.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
    at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
    at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mono.android.D3DImageFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
    at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
    at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I installed Android Studio and Java, and this is still happening. What's up with it?

Comment: You need a 64 bit version of JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following, compared to my setup which works fine (granted I'm on VS 2017):

1. Make sure you have the latest version of Xamarin installed.  Mine are:

   - **Xamarin 4.6.0.299**
   - **Xamarin.Android SDK 7.4.0.21**
2. Make sure your JDK is up to date.  Mine is not up do date, but it does work. So, if you have *at least version jdk1.8.0_112* you should be good.
3. Make sure you are pointing to the 64-bit version of the JDK:

   In Visual Studio go to Tools > Options > Xamarin.
   The "Java Development Kit Location" should be:

   c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112 (or whatever your JDK version is)

   **NOT** c:\Program Files **(x86)**\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

On a side note, if you can easily upgrade to VS 2017 I would recommend that.

Comment: @Allison Sturley Did this help at all?